# How to put a checkbox input inside an alert prompt in Ionic2?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Using Ionic2 and Angular2, I want to show an alert box, inside which a text along with checkbox - to ask for user if he/she agree to the statement.

Comment: Please show us your attempted code so we can help you

Comment: Thanks! problem solved! Answer posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
//Prompt an alert, to ask user to verify there email address.
let alert = Alert.create({
  subTitle: 'Email not verified!',
  message:  'Please check your email for verification link.',
  inputs: [
    {
      name: 'getLink',
      label: 'Get verification link again ?',
      type: "checkbox",
      value: "true",
      checked: false
    }
  ],
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Ok',
      handler: data => {
        console.log(data);
        if(data.length > 0) {
          //console.log('Get me link');
          //we are calling this method to sent a link to user over mail - to verify their email address.
          user.sendEmailVerification(); 
          this.nav.rootNav.setRoot(HomePage);
          return true;
        } else {
          //console.log('Link not required!');
          this.nav.rootNav.setRoot(HomePage);
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  ]
});
this.nav.present(alert);
```

Comment: How can I set it to only one out of multiple options?
I tried adding 

    `multiple : false` 

into the constructor on top of your example but it fails.
Works when you do it through `html` as described [here][1] though...


  [1]: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/select/Select/