# Ionic: Showing an alert controller with a checkbox and text input

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to show a checkbox along with a text input field. (Ionic 3.5.3)

The checkbox is not showing up. I looked at [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569163/ionic2-how-to-put-a-checkbox-input-inside-an-alert-prompt) for a similar question. The code seems to be the same as what I am doing.

The code:

```
let alert = this.alert.create({
      title: 'Name your trip',
      inputs: [
      {
        name: 'name',
        placeholder: 'Your trip name',
      },
      {
         name: 'gpsxy',
         type:'checkbox',
         checked:true,
         label:'Log GPS co-ords',
         value:"true"
      }
    ],

      buttons: [{
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel',
        handler: data => {
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Ok',
        handler: data => {
      }],
    });
    alert.present();
```

And here is the screenshot:[image]

Comment: You can mimic an alert with whatever inputs and elements you want using a modal instead.

Comment: Yes thank you. That is what I plan to do - more work, but only option :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just like you can see in [the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/)

> Alerts can also include several different inputs whose data can be
>   passed back to the app. Inputs can be used as a simple way to prompt
>   users for information. **Radios, checkboxes and text inputs are all
>   accepted, but they cannot be mixed. For example, an alert could have
>   all radio button inputs, or all checkbox inputs, but the same alert
>   cannot mix radio and checkbox inputs.** Do note however, different types
>   of "text"" inputs can be mixed, such as url, email, text, etc. If you
>   require a complex form UI which doesn't fit within the guidelines of
>   an alert then we recommend building the form within a modal instead.

So I'm afraid that it's not possible to do that in Ionic :(

Comment: Thanks! I was about to post, removing the input box showed the GPS checkbox correctly! Argh! But thank you! (I can't accept for answer for the next 10 minutes - how frustrating)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the right thing to do is to create a modal. But I use a workaround, by nesting alerts. I explained and have a working demo in my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65315225/6904938)