# ionic 2 Prompts alert

Tags: ionic2

how to insert radio button and text input inside Prompts alert in ionic 2.
it's work only with text input or radio button. but i want to add radio button group with radio buttons to select only one option and text input in one alert prompt.

my coding

```
  let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Add Course',
  message: "Enter Course Detailes",
  inputs: [

    {
      name: 'id',
      placeholder: 'Course ID'
    },

     {
      name: 'img',
      placeholder: 'Image url'
    },
     {
      name: 'title',
      placeholder: 'Title'
    },
      {
      name: 'Details',
      placeholder: 'Details'
    },
         {
      type:'radio',
      label:'something1',
      value:'something1'
    },
    {
     type:'radio',
     label:'something2',
     value:'something2'
     }
     ],
     buttons : [
     {
     text: "Cancel",
     handler: data => {
     console.log("cancel clicked");
     }
     },
     {
     text: "Save",
     handler: data => {
     console.log("search clicked");
     }
     }
     ]
     });
     prompt.present();
```

[image: output]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ionic: Showing an alert controller with a checkbox and text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45355758/ionic-showing-an-alert-controller-with-a-checkbox-and-text-input)

Comment: Ah @sebaferreras didnt realize there was a dupe

Comment: Np np, I only realized because I've added that answer yesterday lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/):

> Radios, checkboxes and text inputs are all accepted, but they cannot be mixed. For example, an alert could have all radio button inputs, or all checkbox inputs, but the same alert cannot mix radio and checkbox inputs.

You should use a separate component with a [modal controller](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/modal/ModalController/)

```
@Component(...)
class AddCourses {
 courseForm:FormGroup
 constructor(params: NavParams) {
 }
  //create the form reactive or template driven
}
```

In your parent page,

```
 let coursesModal = this.modalCtrl.create(AddCourses, data);
   coursesModal.present();
```